# Google Cast OpenGL ES app

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, chromecast

Is the Google Chromecast capable of streaming an OpenGL ES application and if so what should the proper steps be. I'm using a GLSurfaceView on Android and as of current I can find no tutorials or examples for this online.

Comment: Conceivably the receiver could support WebGL, though I have no idea if it does, and the docs do not seem to suggest that it does. Bear in mind that with Google Cast you are not usually streaming from the Android device to the Cast receiving device. The Android app tells the Cast receiver what to pull from other sources.

Comment: It is my understanding that WebGL isn't currently supported on Chromecast.

Comment: That is correct, WebGL is not currently supported.

Comment: Ok so the receiver doesn't support webgl. But could you perhaps stream a glsurfaceview frame by frame to the receiver?

Comment: Not at any sensible sort of frame rate. External displays can handle that (HDMI, MHL, SlimPort), but even Miracast (WiFiDirect-based display protocol) has lags, and that's all implemented at the hardware level.

Comment: What about normal GLES2 stuff as the GPU on the Chromecast supports it.  I should be able to offload work for the Chromecast device to render.